# .deb packages from internet V/S Snapccraft V/S Flathub

Tags: deb, pop-os, snap, flatpak

I am currently using Pop!_OS 21.10. I want to install MS Teams and there are 3 options for me:
1 - On the website of MS Teams they provide a .deb package that can be installed.
2 - Using Flathub
3 - Using Snapcraft

Which method should I use to install teams? If it would have been there in the official repositories I would have used that. But its not there. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking, it's like asking should I download "this software" from drive, mega or mediafire. They have several 'options' because they're options.

Comment: You should choose the one that's handy for your case and the one that has the most recent versions